# Facebook login without Popup window

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, popup

I am using below code for Facebook login.

```
 function login(){
             FB.login(function(response) {
                   if (response.authResponse) {
                       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                          alert(JSON.stringify(response))

                           });
                   } else {
                       console.log('User did not authorize.');
                   }
               });
       }
```

I am calling login method on click of button.FB.login() call is giving a popup window where user is supposed to enter username and password.

My requirement is to do a silent login i.e. logging in without popup window.My username and pswd are hardcoded for time being.How do i pass the credentials to login API without user intervention.I know hardcoding is not good practice but later i will obtain credentials from user controls.

How do i achieve this.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think a popup is now required for security reasons. Obtaining credentials yourself is definitely not a good idea, as you could easily store them accidentally and you shouldn't have access to them at all.

Comment: Thank you.But I am thinking to programatically fill in text boxes in popup and generate click event on login button in popup as a final try.Since popup is an another window, does this approach work in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The frame that hosts the login is an iFrame displaying a form page hosted on Facebook. Facebook doesn't want computers logging people into their site for various anti-spam, security reasons.

Comment: I'm wondering- are you setting up automated testing? Depending on testing technology, there are ones that will enter in text for you, as the client.

Comment: Not testing actually.It is that I just dont want the popup window because that behaviour is ok when my webpage containing login button runs in desktop browser, but the page is intended to run in mobile browsers and i am not sure how it behaves there.Since I dont have device to test I thought to abandon the idea of new window for login.

Comment: In Mobile, android & iPhone, the SDKs manage and design their own custom Facebook dialog windows. You call the method that displays the dialog, and manage the callback methods.

Comment: Yeah, and users are used to the look and feel of Facebook logins, so best not to mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for several reasons

1. It is against Facebook's Policy to give credentials to third parties
2. Users should always be able to verify the identity of the page they are giving their credentials to.

I'm sure you don't want to require your users to break the policy do you?